# The process has no code signature

Tags: macos

I run Little Snitch on my Mac, and when I run the Monero GUI, it warns me numerous times "The process has no code signature. The executable can be maliciously modified without being detected." for many, many IP addresses.

Is this normal?

I see a lot of outgoing traffic, too, and I'm curious: why is Monero so chatty through a process that has no code signature and is susceptible to being modified? Isn't that a fairly large security risk?

Comment: See https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/316/4206

Answer (score 1):

The Monero developers didn't bother to buy an Apple developer license, so that's why the binary isn't signed and thus throws up that error.

Comment: So is the vulnerability to being modified without detection not a concern?

Comment: No. You can check the GPG signed SHA256 hashes of the binaries.